# How to get started with applying item response theory and what software to use?

Tags: psychometrics, latent-variable, item-response-theory

#### Context

I have been reading about item response theory, and I find it fascinating. I believe I understand the basics, but I am left wondering how to apply statistical techniques related to the area. Below are two articles that are similar to the area I would like to apply ITR in:

- http://www.jstor.org/stable/4640738?seq=7
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21744971

The second being the one I would actually like to extend at this point in time.

I have downloaded a free program called jMetrik, and it seems to be working great. I think it may be too basic as far as IRT goes, but I am unsure.

I know the "best" way would likely involve learning R; however, I don't know if I can spare the time to tackle that learning curve. Note that we have some funding to purchase software, but from what I see, there doesn't seem to be any great IRT programs out there.

#### Questions

- What are your thoughts on the effectiveness of jMetrik?
- How would you suggest I go forward in applying IRT?
- What are the best programs for applying IRT?
- Do any of you use IRT regularly? If so, how?

Comment: what software do you currently use?

Comment: I have been using jMetrik. It is quite new it looks like and has been doing a lot of the things I am interested in!

Comment: Does it work in a script mode? If you only have a GUI, then your results will be very difficult to reproduce. A script mode is a must for any serious software.

Comment: It has a log export feature.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a good starter to IRT, I always recommend reading [A visual guide to item response theory](http://www.metheval.uni-jena.de/irt/VisualIRT.pdf).

A survey of available software can be found on [www.rasch.org](http://www.rasch.org/software.htm).

From my experience, I found the [Raschtest](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0119) (and associated) Stata command(s) very handy in most cases where one is interested in fitting one-parameter model. For more complex design, one can resort on [GLLAMM](http://www.gllamm.org/); there's a nice [working example](http://www.gllamm.org/aggression.html) based on De Boeck and Wilson's book, *Explanatory Item and Response Models* (Springer, 2004).

About R specifically, there are plenty of packages that have become available in the past five years, see for instance the related CRAN [Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html). Most of them are discussed in a [special issue](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20) of the *Journal of Statistical Software* (vol. 20, 2007). As discussed in another response, the [ltm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/index.html) and [eRm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eRm/index.html) allow to fit a wide range of IRT models. As they rely on different method of estimation---`ltm` used the marginal approach while `eRm` use the conditional approach---choosing one or the other is mainly a matter of the model you want to fit (`eRm` won't fit 2- or 3-parameter models) and the measurement objective you follow: conditional estimation of person parameters has some nice psychometric properties while a marginal approach let you easily switch to mixed-effects model, as discussed in the following two papers:

- Doran, H., Bates, D., Bliese, P. and Dowling, M. (2007). [Estimating the Multilevel Rasch Model: With the lme4 Package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20/i02). *Journal of Statistical Software*, 20(2). See also Doug Bates's [slides on R-forge](http://lme4.R-forge.R-project.org/)
- De Boeck, P., Bakker, M., Zwitser, R., Nivard, M., Hofman, A., Tuerlinckx, F., and Partchev, I. (2011). [The Estimation of Item Response Models with the lmer Function from the lme4 Package in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i12). *Journal of Statistical Software*, 39(12). See also the aforementioned De Boeck's handbook and this [handout](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/deboeck/materials/handouts.pdf)

There are also some possibilities to fit Rasch models using MCMC methods, see e.g. the [MCMCpack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCpack/) package (or [WinBUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/winbugs/contents.shtml)/[JAGS](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/), but see [BUGS Code for Item Response Theory](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v36/c01/paper), JSS (2010) 36).

I have no experience with SAS for IRT modeling, so I'll let that to someone who is more versed into SAS programming.

Other dedicated software (mostly used in educational assessment) include: RUMM, Conquest, Winsteps, BILOG/MULTILOG, Mplus (not citing the list already available on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometric_software)). None are free to use, but time-limited demonstration version are proposed for some of them. I found [jMetrik](http://www.itemanalysis.com/) very limited when I tried it (one year ago), and all functionalities are already available in R. Likewise, [ConstructMap](http://bearcenter.berkeley.edu/ConstructMap/) can be safely replaced by [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html), as illustrated in the [handout](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/deboeck/materials/handouts.pdf) linked above.
I should also mention `mdltm` (Multidimensional Discrete Latent Trait Models) for mixture Rasch models, by von Davier and coll., which is supposed to accompagny the book *Multivariate and Mixture Distribution Rasch Models* (Springer, 2007).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the very comprehensive answer! Both of these answers will help me nicely, as well as anyone else who is curious in pursuing this area I'm sure. I do suggest you take a look at jMetrik again, and perhaps give me your thoughts. It has Rasch modelling now, ICC curves, some IRT curves, IRT equating (1PT, 2PT, 3PT models), and more.

Comment: I will look at the updated version. But, honestly, what @Stask said is worth to remember if you plan to do anything serious beyond parameters estimation and visual reporting. To get an idea of what I mean, look at [An introduction to psychometric theory with applications in R](http://personality-project.org/r/book/). (It covers more than just what some call "modern" psychometrics.)

Comment: @chi - I got very different results when I ran IRT analyses in R using ltm compared to when I ran the same analysis in Mplus and then in Multilog (whereas analysis in Mplus and Multilog were identical). I tried to work out why with the author of ltm, but did not receive any responses. Have you had any similar experiences with discrepant results from different software packages?

Comment: @Tormod Very different in what sense? Running the `ex5.5` example in Mplus and R/ltm, I got approx. the same results. Some variations depending on software being used are to be expected, though. Usually, what I've found is related to the choice of the parametrization (logit/probit), whether it's $\theta_p-\beta_i$ ($i=1,\dots,k$ items, $p=1,\dots,n$ persons) or $\beta_i-\theta_p$ that is modeled, and the estimation method (marginal vs. conditional likelihood), and for 2+ parameter models whether thresholds are centered or not.

Comment: @chi - sorry for the delay in response, I haven't noticed your comment. Don't know if this is still relevant, but I got differences varying from 0.184 - 1.429 for the discrimination parameters (a). For example, Mplus gave an a=5.084 whereas ltm gave the same item an a=3.655. Overall, ltm gave smaller a's than mplus. (Running the same analyses in multilog gave a's corresponding to the a's from Mplus). The b's were more similiar.

Comment: @Tormod Will check again and come back to you asap.

Answer (score 8):

To the first question, I don't have any information about jMetrick.

In applying IRT, (as with any other statistical procedure) the first step is to use it with as many different kinds of data as possible. There is a learning curve, but I believe that it is worth it.

One important feature of IRT is the differentiation between Rasch models and IRT models. They were developed by different people for different purposes. That being said, IRT models are a superset of Rasch models.

Rasch models are one parameter models - they assume that all items on a questionnaire are equally predictive of the latent trait.

IRT models, however are two parameter models which allow the questions to differ in their ability to provide information about the ability of participants.

In addition, there are three parameter models which are like the IRT models, except that they allow for a guessing parameter to account for participants ability to get the right answer by chance (this is more of a concern in ability rather than personality tests).

In addition, there is multidimensional IRT which estimates multiple latent abilities at once. I don't know much about this, but its an area which I intend to learn more.

There is also a distinction between dichotomous and polytomous IRT methods. Dichotomous IRT models are those used in ability tests, which have a right and wrong answer. Polytomous IRT models are used in personality tests, where there are multiple answers, which are equally right (in the sense that there is no correct answer).

I personally use R for item response theory. There are two main packages that I have used, `eRm` which fits Rasch models only, and `ltm` which fits item response theory models (two and three parameter models). Both have similiar functionality, and both provide more routines for dichotomous IRT models. I don't know if R is the "best" for IRT, it does not have all of the multitude of IRT models available, but it is certainly the most extensible, in that one can program these models relatively easily.

I use IRT almost exclusively for polytomous models, in R. I typically start with non parametric IRT methods (provided in the package `mokken`) to test the assumptions, and then proceed with a rasch model, adding more complexity as required to get good fit.

For multidimensional IRT, there is the package `mirt', which provides this functionality. I have not used it so I cannot really comment.

If you do install these packages into R, and call the 'vignette("packagename")' function then you should get some useful vignettes (definitely for `eRm` and `mokken`, possibly for the others) which may prove useful for you (depending on your level of mathematical sophistication).

Finally, there are a number of good books available for rasch and irt models. [Item response theory for psychologists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805828192) is often used (though I didn't like the style), and further up the technical sophistication chain, there are two extremely comprehensive and useful textbooks - the [Handbook of Modern Item Response Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441928499) and [Rasch Models:Foundations, Recent Developments and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387944990).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That is much appreciated. I would also like to hear more about software options if someone has some knowledge in the area.

Answer (score 3):

jMetrik is more powerful than you may think. It is designed for operational work where researchers need multiple procedures in a single unified framework. Currently you can estimate IRT parameters for the Rasch, partial credit and rating scale models. It also allows for IRT scale linking via the Stocking-Lord, Haebara and other methods. Because it includes an integrated database, the output from the IRT estimation can be used in scale linking without the need to reshape data files. Moreover, all output can be stored in the database for use with other methods in jMetrik or external programs like R.

You can also run it with scripts instead of the GUI. For example, the follwing code will (a) import data into the database, (b) score items with an answer key, (c) estimate Rasch model parameters, and (d) export data as a CSV file. You can use the final output file as input into R for further analysis, or you can use R to connect directly to the jMetrik database and work with the results.

```
#import data into database
import{
     delimiter(comma);
     header(included);
     options(display);
     description();
     file(C:/exam1-raw-data.txt);
     data(db = testdb1, table = EXAM1);
}

#conduct item scoring with the answer key
scoring{
     data(db = mydb, table = exam1);
     keys(4);
     key1(options=(A,B,C,D), scores=(1,0,0,0), variables=  (item1,item9,item12,item15,item19,item21,item22,item28,item29,item30,item34,item38,item42,item52,item55));
     key2(options=(A,B,C,D), scores=(0,1,0,0), variables=(item4,item6,item16,item18,item24,item26,item32,item33,item35,item43,item44,item47,item50,item54));
     key3(options=(A,B,C,D), scores=(0,0,1,0), variables=(item3,item5,item7,item11,item14,item20,item23,item25,item31,item40,item45,item48,item49,item53));
     key4(options=(A,B,C,D), scores=(0,0,0,1), variables=(item2,item8,item10,item13,item17,item27,item36,item37,item39,item41,item46,item51,item56));
}

#Run a Rasch models analysis.
#Item parameters saved as database table named exam1_rasch_output
#Residuals saved as a databse table named exam1_rasch_resid
#Person estimates saved to original data table. Person estimate in variable called "theta"
rasch{
     center(items);
     missing(ignore);
     person(rsave, pfit, psave);
     item(isave);
     adjust(0.3);
     itemout(EXAM1_RASCH_OUTPUT);
     residout(EXAM1_RASCH_RESID);
     variables(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13, item14, item15, item16, item17, item18, item19, item20, item21, item22, item23, item24, item25, item26, item27, item28, item29, item30, item31, item32, item33, item34, item35, item36, item37, item38, item39, item40, item41, item42, item43, item44, item45, item46, item47, item48, item49, item50, item51, item52, item53, item54, item55, item56);
     transform(scale = 1.0, precision = 4, intercept = 0.0);
     gupdate(maxiter = 150, converge = 0.005);
     data(db = testdb1, table = EXAM1);
}

#Export output table for use in another program like R
export{
     delimiter(comma);
     header(included);
     options();
     file(C:/EXAM1_RASCH_OUTPUT.txt);
     data(db = testdb1, table = EXAM1_RASCH_OUTPUT);
}
```

The software is still in its early stages of development. I am currently adding exploratory factor analysis and more advanced item response models. Unlike many other IRT programs, jMetrik is open source. all of the measurement procedures use the psychometrics library which is currently available on GitHub, https://github.com/meyerjp3/psychometrics. Anyone interested in contributing is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Many important developments have been made in item response theory (IRT) software since you first asked your question, so an updated answer may be in order. This being said, [a visual guide to item response theory](https://www.slideshare.net/ahmadrustam1/a-visual-guide-to-item-response-theory) remains a great reference, so I second @chl's recommendation$^1$.

Software packages mentioned above can be categorized as either IRT specialized software (e.g., `BILOG/MULTILOG`, `Xcalibre`, `jMetrik`, and `R` packages such as `ltm`) or more general purpose statistical software (e.g., `MPLUS`, `SAS`, `STATA`, and `R` packages such as `lme4`). While these packages differ in important ways, most can accommodate the most commonly used IRT models such as the two-parameter logistic (2PL) model, graded response model (GRM), Rasch/one-parameter logistic (1PL) model, & generalized partial credit model (GPCM)$^2$.

While opinions may vary, the state of the art IRT software packages today are `flexMIRT` - a proprietary software package that specializes in IRT models and related methods, and `mirt` an `R` package. Both packages not only can accommodate the IRT models mentioned above, they are also the most up to date when it comes to state of the art estimation algorithms and model fit information. For example, both implement the Metropolis-Hastings Robbins-Monro (MHRM) algorithm (Cai 2010a, & Cai 2010b), which allows for efficient estimation of high dimensional IRT models. Additionally, both incorporate recent developments in global model fit (e.g., see Cai, Chung, & Lee, 2023; and  Maydeu-Olivares 2014 for more information) and piecewise model fit. For these reasons, `flexMIRT` and `mirt` are the IRT packages I use the most.

$^1$ A number of good books have also recently been published. Bonifay (2019) is a good introduction for readers new to IRT, and Bock & Gibbons (2021) is a good reference for individuals with more experience with psychological measurement and/or statistics.

$^2$ See Thissen & Steinberg (1986) for a great overview of IRT models.

**References**

Bock, R. D., & Gibbons, R. D. (2021). Item response theory. John Wiley & Sons.

Bonifay, W. (2019). Multidimensional item response theory. Sage Publications.

Cai, L. (2010). High-dimensional exploratory item factor analysis by a Metropolis–Hastings Robbins–Monro algorithm. Psychometrika, 75, 33-57.

Cai, L. (2010). Metropolis-Hastings Robbins-Monro algorithm for confirmatory item factor analysis. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 35(3), 307-335.

Cai, L., Chung, S. W., & Lee, T. (2023). Incremental model fit assessment in the case of categorical data: Tucker–lewis index for item response theory modeling. Prevention Science, 24(3), 455-466.

Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2014). Evaluating the fit of IRT models. In Handbook of item response theory modeling (pp. 111-127). Routledge.

Thissen, D., & Steinberg, L. (1986). A taxonomy of item response models. Psychometrika, 51(4), 567-577.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a broad list of questions here, but quite relevant for many researchers!

I highly recommend you go forward in IRT, but only if your situation meets the requirements.  For example, it fits well with the types of tests you use, and probably most importantly that you have the necessary sample sizes.  For dichotomous multiple-choice data, I recommend the 3PL model (the Rasch argument of "objective measurement" is strikingly uncompelling), and 500-1000 is generally the minimum sample size.  Dichotomous data without guessing, like psychological surveys that have Y/N responses to statements, work well with the 2PL.  If you have rating scale or partial credit data, there are polytomous models designed specifically for those situations.

IMHO, the best program for applying IRT is Xcalibre.  It is relatively user-friendly (simple GUI as well as some command-line batch-type if you want it for some reason) and produces highly readable output (MS Word reports with extensive tables and figures).  I recommend against using R for the opposite reasons.  The drawback, of course, is that it is not free, but you tend to get what you pay for as they say.  Full description, example output, and a free trial are available at [www.assess.com](http://www.assess.com).

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on why the argument on "objective measurement" sensu Rasch (or more correctly the possibility of specific objective comparisons) is "strikingly uncompelling"?

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time there has published a new book by Frank Baker, [Baker Frank B. , Seock-Ho Kim. The Basics of Item Response Theory Using R. Springer International Publishing (2017)](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319542041). It does not make use of R packages but offers snippets.

A (crowded) list of R packages for IRT with succinct description is available on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html).