# How to predict 4 dependent ordinal DV from 6 ordinal/nominal IVs

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ordinal-data, manova

My question is simple. I got 4 ordinal variables and I wish to investigate the extent that other 6 ordinal/nominal variables predicts their values. I know that ordinal regression is the appropriate method of predicting those 4 ordinal responses one by one however, since the 4 ordinal variables are also statistically dependent (as chi square verifies) I wonder if there is a method analogous to MANOVA for the continuous case to help me investigate the power of prediction of the 6 IVs to the set of 4 DV taking into account the fact that they are statistically dependent.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You could do this as a multilevel model or as a structural equation model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible approaches may be to perform so called *optimal scaling* on your 4 ordinal response variables. This a procedure to transform ordinal scale into interval scale under the aim to maximize linear correlation among the dependent variables or between the dependent variables and some independent ones. ([Some techniques using](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31297/3277) optimal scaling.)

I suppose you are interested in the latter aim and so you will need **Categorical canonical correlation analysis by optimal scaling** (OVERALS). Like linear canonical correlation analysis, it maximizes correlation between sets of variables, in your case - the dependent set and the independent set, - but it does it allowing for nonlinear transform of "ordinal" variables into "interval" ones. Aptly may be noticed here that usual (linear) MANOVA is ([closely related to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31468/3277)) linear canonical correlation analysis, so saying "I want MANOVA" is echoed by "take canonical analysis".

The optimal scaling method just described is an alternative to *multilevel generalized linear modelling* suggested by @Jeremy in his comment. I can't say which way is "better". The difference between the *optimal scaling* and the *generalizing* approaches is that the first assumes a specific *mode of explicit transform* from ordinal to interval "underlying variable", whereas the second assumes a specific *kind of distribution* for that interval "underlying variable" by utilizing a corresponding implicit link function and minimizing errors w.r.t. to the observed variable.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and instructions. Although I am not quite sure about how I will finally make the analysis, I have a good understanding for the possible alternatives.