# Factor analysis on non normal data ( Ordinal data of Likert Scale)

Tags: factor-analysis, ordinal-data, likert

How to check the normality of data collected on 5 point Likert scale?

As it is ordinal numbers not continuous. Using SPSS the Shapiro Wilk or Kolmogorov-Smirnov test indicate my data is not normal.

I am validating the existing frameworks so most of the values (mean) are between 3.5- 4.5

Can I go ahead with factor analysis? If yes then are there any constraints for the same?

Comment: Likert scale data is not normal. 
It's discrete, so it can't be normal. 
It's bounded on both sides, so it can't be normal. 
It's *ordinal*. It's not normal. Why would you test it, which can at best tell you what you already know?

Comment: The big question isn't whether your data are normal (we know it's not), it's how much the non-normality you have impacts any inference in your factor analysis.

Comment: [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/factor-analysis-of-questionnaires-composed-of-likert-items?rq=1) seems like a potential duplicate.

Comment: In addition to the preceding comments, there are methods to handle categorical variables with ordered levels that do not rely on classical multivariate normal assumptions in CFA, as implemented in, e.g., [Mplus](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mplus/seminars/IntroMplus_CFA/), or using an alternative statistical framework, e.g., [IRT modeling](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27927/930).

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use `R`, you can use `sem` and `polycor` packages to do exploratory or confirmatory analysis based on ordinal data. See [the manual here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sem/sem.pdf). It first computes a polychoric correlation matrix as input. If you are not familiar with polychoric correlation, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation) about its assumptions and examples.

If you do not know how to use `R`, you can compute polychoric correlations among the ordinal variables and submit the correlation matrix to SPSS/AMOS as input. I do believe SPSS/AMOS takes a correlation matrix as input. It seems, though, you need the SPSS Categories Module to compute polychoric correlations.